# Absolute convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n (1-\cos1/n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to see if $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(1-\cos \frac{1}{n}\right)$$ converges absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donote your sum by $S$. Taylor series for $\cos$ gives us $\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)$, hence $1 - \cos x = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)$. Since $|(-1)^n (1-\cos\frac{1}{n})| = \cos\frac{1}{n}$, it follows that

$$S \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^2} + |o(\frac{1}{n^3})|\right).$$

Since $\frac{o(x^3)}{x^3}\to 0 $, when $x\to 0$, we know that $o(x^3)\leq x^3$ for all $|x|\leq x_0$ for some $x_0\in (0,\infty)$. It follows that

$$S\leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{n_0}o(\frac{1}{n^3}) + \sum_{n = n_0 + 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}<\infty$$
where $n_0$ is a integer for which $\frac{1}{n_0}\leq x_0$.

Answer (score 4):

hint: $1-\cos(u)=2*\sin(u/2)^2$  and $\sin(u) \sim u$ when $u\to 0$

Answer (score 3):

By the Taylor series

$$\left| (-1)^n (1-\cos \frac{1}{n})\right|\sim_\infty\frac1{2n^2}$$
and the Riemann series $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ is convergent so the given series is absolutely convergent by comparison.

Comment: Nice use of the Taylor series! I should remember to give this a try.